# Azure Connection Fails for type sftpwithssh - "Invalid private key file."

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have an Azure Logic App that calls an API which results in a file.  I need to move the file to a folder using an sftpwithssh connection.  Attempts to configure the connection result in an error,, then  "Invalid private key file."

I've attempted to create the connection from All Resources > Add "sftpwithssh" connection by providing the parameters in "Edit API Connection".  I also attempted to create a new conenction while editing the Logic App during the Change Connection process.  Both attempts produce the same error.

I've confirmed that the key is valid by sending the file using WinSCP client app.  I pasted the key string into the Azure Connection configuration using the instructions to highlight and copy.

I found one post that recommends that I use the code view instead of designer view to provide the connection information, but I'm uncertain of the formal parameters names needed.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your post provided the insight to resolve this problem.  I downloaded puTTY Key Generator app and converted the key string to OpenSSH key.  Our Azure sftpwithssh connection no longer reports an error.  Thank you Martin!

Comment: Hi ghoh, since you have solved the problem, could you please post an answer below ? It may help other communities.